# Datagrid will not display decrypted XML data after saving the file...do I need to close the streamwriter?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, datagridview, deserialization

I'm working on data decryption and I'm using a datagrid to view the data.  The problem occurs after I edit and save an existing record.  After the save process the data is decrypted but if any data row is clicked the data suddenly becomes encrypted.  Is the streamwriter responsible for this?  Do I need to close the streamwriter?

```
namespace someProgram
{
    public partial class formManage : Form
    {
        private readonly XmlSerializer xs;
        private AddressBook ls;
        private int _counter = 0;
        private string currentFileName;
        public string title { get; set; }
        int selectedRow;
        private static Random random = new Random();

        public formManage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            ls = new AddressBook();
            xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(AddressBook));
            currentFileName = "";
        }

        public void saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
            saveFileDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;
            saveFileDialog.Title = "Select save location file name";
            saveFileDialog.Filter = "XML-File | *.xml";
            if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(saveFileDialog.FileName)

                    SaveFile(writer);

            }
        }

        public void SaveFile(StreamWriter writer)
        {
            foreach (var item in ls.Contacts)
            {
                item.Question1 = XMLEncryption.Model.Helpers.Encryptor.Encrypt(item.Question1);
                item.Question2 = XMLEncryption.Model.Helpers.Encryptor.Encrypt(item.Question2);
                item.Question3 = XMLEncryption.Model.Helpers.Encryptor.Encrypt(item.Question3);
            }
            xs.Serialize(writer, ls);
            MessageBox.Show("File saved... ");
        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            selectedRow = e.RowIndex;
            if (selectedRow >= 0)
            {
                buttonUpdate.Enabled = true;
                DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.Rows[selectedRow];

                if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
                {
                    string question1 = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[4].Value + string.Empty;
                    string question2 = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[6].Value + string.Empty;
                    string question3 = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[8].Value + string.Empty;

                    textBoxQuestion1.Text = question1;
                    textBoxQuestion2.Text = question2;
                    textBoxQuestion3.Text = question3;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Test you project in smaller piece.  Make sure the encrypt and decrypt methods work  The test the DGV methods work.  Your question is much too broad to give a specific answer.

Comment: The encrypted and decrypted methods work as expected.  The datagridview also works as expected and this is the abbreviated version of the project.  It appears that the streamreader is responsible for this but I'm not sure how to fix it

Comment: Before deserializing the xml you must decrypt the data.  So decrypt before call the deserializer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to encrypt the questions of the Address Book that you are using in memory? If not you could just create a new instance of the address book that is encrypted at the time of saving.

```
public void SaveFile(StreamWriter writer)
{
    AddressBook encryptedBook = New AddressBook();

    foreach (var item in ls.Contacts)
    {
        var encryptedContact = new Contact
        {
            Question1 = XMLEncryption.Model.Helpers.Encryptor.Encrypt(item.Question1),
            Question2 = XMLEncryption.Model.Helpers.Encryptor.Encrypt(item.Question2),
            Question3 = XMLEncryption.Model.Helpers.Encryptor.Encrypt(item.Question3)
        };

        encryptedBook.Contacts.Add(encryptedContact);
    }

    xs.Serialize(writer, encryptedBook);
    MessageBox.Show("File saved... ");
}
```

Comment: I tried this solution and I get the same result.  Also, I updated the original post.  After deeper debugging I found the problem is when I save.  It seems that after the save the file is no longer deserialized but I still cant figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.  For objects that implement iDispose like streamreader and streamwriter...the "Using" statement should be used which will automatically dispose the streams.  for ex...

```
using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("myfile.txt")){//do stuff here}
```

this ensures the streamreader is disposed of and I can reload the document by either reloading the page or calling the open routine.  Essentially everywhere I use the stream read or write classes I wrapped them in a using statement and the bug is resolved because the stream was properly disposed.